# Multiple runners for enclosed junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

[image]

Enclosed junit test showing multiple runners to select from. Is there any way that it show only one parent runner.

When running this test alone then runner can be selected easily.

But when running test package in which this test resides with other tests, Junit shows errors as the enclosed tests run twice. One time it shows success and second time it shows error.

I want them to run just once.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little unclear what the problem is here. What is happening that you don't like? And what would you like to happen?

Comment: See the latest image added, I have two tests in java project package, one is 'EnclosedTest' and other is 'OtherTest'. I have selected whole package and run that as junit test. Enclosed tests are visible two times,  but they are running successfully just once. Note: enclosed is the package name. Don't get confused with that ;)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I have reproduced this locally. I'm not having any failures reported, which is good, but it does seem to be running tests multiple times. Adding sysouts in test1 and test 2 and test3(OtherTest), I get the following output from running the tests at the package level: 1
3
1
2
2

Comment: And choosing to run just EnclosedTest from within Eclipse does prompt me as to which test I want to run as in your first screenshot

Comment: Note: This doesn't happen when I run the test through Ant, so perhaps it is a quirk of running this kind of test through an IDE